# Using curl to upload source map to getsentry failed

Tags: curl, file-upload, sentry

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/2513

`curl https://app.getsentry.com/api/0/projects/instawork/production/releases/:version/files/ -u [:api_key]: -X POST -F file=@webpack.js.map -F name="https://www.instawork.com/static/js/webpack.js.map"`

I get the following error: $ curl: (26) couldn't open file "webpack.js.map"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved in the linked GitHub issue — your user likely does not have read permissions on the "webpack.js.map" file.

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 mistakes here:

1. When uploading from my local file system, 

   `-F file=@"aaa/xxxx.map"`

   'aaa' needs to be the full path to the file I wanted to upload. eg. Users/name/mydir/
2. As mentioned by @ehfeng. Also need to make sure that I have the permission.